# How can I send an object using axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

Is there a way to send an object to an API using axios?

This the code I use:

```
axios.get('/api/phones/create/', {
    parameters: {
        phone: this.phone
    }
})
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

on the php side, I have the following:

```
public function create($phone)
{
    return $phone;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
GET http://crm2.dev/api/phones/create 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.6007af59798a7b58ff81.js:256
xhrAdapter @ app.6007af59798a7b58ff81.js:93
dispatchRequest @ app.6007af59798a7b58ff81.js:662
app.6007af59798a7b58ff81.js:2266 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.6007af59798a7b58ff81.js:600)
    at settle (app.6007af59798a7b58ff81.js:742)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.6007af59798a7b58ff81.js:158)
```

If I try, `axios.get('/api/phones/create/hello')` I get `hello` in the console log.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure, but `Request failed with status code 500` says that is server side problem

Comment: part of the error was indeed on the php method: I did this instead: `public function create(Request $request)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "send an object".

Since you're using a GET request and passing the object in the parameters, you can serialize it into query params as part of the GET request. This wouldn't really send the object but rather use it to build the query section of the URL for the GET request.

For example, here's how you can make a request to `/api/phones/create?phone=123`:

```
axios.get('/api/phones/create/', {
    params: {
        phone: '123'
    }
})
```

If you want to actually send the object as a serialized JSON to your API, you can use a POST or a PUT request, depending on the semantics of your API.

For example, to send `{ "phone": "123" }` to your api, you could do:

```
axios.post('/api/phones/create/', {
  phone: '123'
});
```

**Note**: axios expects the key `params` for parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot. I forgot that the sent params were part of the request.
PS: I'm using a GET request to get the default data to create a phone. In the store method, I use a POST request. This works perfectly. Thanks you.

Comment: @Warrio no problem mate, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all  try with `params` instead of `parameters`.

**Axios rely on promises** you might need to [add promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) to your code if you want to support old browsers.

Here is sample request, Read [official docs](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for more information.

```
axios.get('/url', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```